# How do you transfer parameters to other websites?

Tags: reactjs, rest, post, parameters

I have two websites. I'll call one "aaa.com" and the other "bbb.com."

When I press any button in "aaa.com", I want to transfer the parameters that the button has while connecting to the "bbb.com".

Which way can I choose?
Both websites are made of React.

Comment: Use them in iframe

Comment: and..? how to transfer parameters in iframe

Comment: try this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the site as an iFrame and try post message from parent to child [See this article](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)